# Replacing slip on bathtub spout

Tags: bathtub

What order do I stack the o rings and washers on in order to keep the spout from leaking? It is a slip on spout.

Comment: Its a tad hard to visuslise without more information such as a photo

Answer (score 1):

Normally it would be the o-ring first then the washer. If it is still leaking replace the o-ring or use some plumber grease.